# Solutions for $x^2+y^2=2007$ and reference request.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, modular-arithmetic

I have never formally studied number theory, it is not a part of my course work, and what I have learnt is reading Wikipedia or the answers here. This question was on a test and I tried to use quadratic residues to solve this.

Find the number of solutions in integers to:

$$x^2+y^2=2007$$

We can observe that $2007\equiv 0\pmod3$

$x^2\equiv0,1\pmod{3}$, $y^2\equiv0,1\pmod{3}$

Since these can never add up to $3$,we conclude that $x$, $y$ are divisible by $3$

Let $x=3x'$, $y=3y'$

$$(x')^2+(y')^2=223$$

Since $223\equiv 3\pmod4$ but $x^2\equiv 0,1\pmod{4}$ we conclude there are no solutions.

Is this argument correct? Also how else could this question have been solved? (Considering the fact that we don't have modular arithmetic in our syllabus, and therefore the teacher was probably expecting something else)

Also where can I study number theory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$2007\equiv3\equiv-1\pmod4$$

But $\displaystyle a\equiv0,\pm1,2\pmod4\implies a^2\equiv0,1\pmod4$

So, what are possible values of $\displaystyle x^2+y^2\pmod 4$

Comment: ah that was a lot shorter. but could you read through and answer the second part? Where can I *study* number theory formally?

Comment: @Sabyasachi, Find my answer and comment here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1

Comment: okay thanks.${}$

Answer (score 0):

Any perfect square is of the form $4k, 4k+1, $ $ 2007$ is of the form $ 4k+3$, and in no possible way can two perfect squares $(4k$, or $4k+1)$ form add up to produce number of the form $4k+3$ and hence this has no solutions